# How to debug this regular expression on CodinGame?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to solve this puzzle on CodinGame
https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/cgx-formatter

In this puzzle you get some text as input and have to format it in a certain way. My approach is to check the start of the input if its a number, string, boolean, parentheses enclosed block, etc. I remove the part that matches from the input string and build my Element Objects. When I am done, I print the elements over a toString method.

I have trouble with discerning a `'string'` from a `'key'=something`. I want to match everything that is at the start of the input, enclosed in '' and not followed by a `=`. There can be spaces or tabs between the key and the `=`.

The if clause:

```
if(concat.matches("^'.*'.*")  && !concat.matches("^'.*'\\s*=")){
    System.err.println("Test");
}
```

evaluates true (incorrectly) for the String `'key'='value'`. What am I doing wrong?

`concat` is the input String concatenated into one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
"^'([^']*)'[ \t]*[^=]*$"
```

() is your match, key without quotes.

This will match any string starting with a single-quote, followed by any number of any char except single-quote until single-quote, after that any number (including zero) of spaces or tabs may occur and after that any number (including zero) of any char (excluding equal sign) may occur until the end of the line.